# Channel Form with Grid and File - "There was a problem with one or more Grid fields"

Tags: channel-form, grid

I have a standard channel form in a template with a number of fields that work fine.

I'm using a grid field that contains one file fieldtype.

No matter what I try I get "There was a problem with one or more Grid fields". I've checked upload location permissions, posting permissions and anything else that's a common problem. Console isn't showing any errors or missing assets and template and php debugging similarly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

PS. The grid and file fields are working fine from the admin interface.

Comment: Do you have the channel form css file included: <link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - yes, it's included and accessible

Comment: I am also having this problem, but only when submitting the form as a Guest user. When I am logged in it works fine. Did you ever resolve the problem?

Comment: I didn't I'm afraid - thankfully the client had other pressing issues to crack on with so it's still in an unresolved state. The only advice I'd managed to find was "reinstall EE" and that's something I'm not prepared to do (again!). If I have any luck I'll come back to update this thread.

Comment: For the record, you shouldn't have to reinstall EE to fix anything. Check PHP error logs & browser console for errors.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. Come to find out, it wasn't grid that was the culprit even though it was flagging grid as the error. EE just changed some code and that really effects how some add-ons function.

One of the big issues with using Add-ons is when the developer forgets to use "remove_package_path()" when they are finished with it. Forgetting this not only causes the following fieldtypes to use the same path which is, in turn incorrect, but makes debugging a nightmare.

I haven't had any issues with my DevDemon addons, but others have caused random issues.

If you know enough to crawl through the source files, you can correct it yourself until the developer decides to update.

You could start eliminating them one by one to find out which one is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but is it also what google gave me for this issue, and it doesn't have an answer yet but I just fixed my problem with 2 possible things that may have been giving this error. 
Seems obvious now, but it's often the obvious things that trip you up.

I was using Grid field with a file field (both native EE)

1. I was trying to upload a file type that wasn't allowed in the particular directory I had assigned to the file field

AND

2. The user group of the user I was logged in as didn't have permission to access the directory assigned to the file field. Both of these corrected the error has stopped.